# shortcut key to get the previous command in ksh

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ksh

Shortcut key to get the previous command in `ksh`

- What is the shorcut key to get the previous command that was used in `ksh`?
- I have tried using the history command but that is not my requirement.
- I want to know the `shortcut key`.

Comment: Do you want to simply re-execute the command, or do you want to edit it first?

Answer (score 1):

If you first set the editor mode to "vi";

```
set -o vi
```

Then you can access history by entering command mode (press Esc key), and using either the up arrow or the 'k' key.

From there, vi editing syntax works - e.g. to edit the line enter insert mode ('i') etc. Hitting return will re-execute the command, and Ctrl-C will cancel.